# Postback is not firing when I click on the submit button, works fine on the server

Tags: asp.net, webforms, postback

Locally when I am in running my asp.net webforms application the submit button all of a sudden stopped posting back.

So my onClick events do not fire, and Page.IsPostBack is always false.

When I push the code to my server, everything works fine.

I tried running it in both IIS express and setting up a website locally in IIS, the result is the same.

What could the problem be?

I don't see any javascript errors in chrome console either, but it is working in production so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, but if the onClick and submit button don't work, why is the Page ever loading again to check IsPostBack?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: do you mean onClick or Click? javascript click or server control click? also, sometimes removing/deleting a button and putting on a new one can fix mystery problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had made an update to the web.config to enforce secure cookies, and when I did running the application locally caused the no post back behaviour.

My guess is that the asp.net session cookie was not able to be saved, so the postback was also not working.

The change I made was:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```